# Update table field in database depending on whether it's the latest entry

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table and there's been some duplicates entered into it.

I don't want to remove the duplicates but I want to set an indicator on the some of the records which are not the latest entry (the highest reviewid is the latest)

My table is as follows:

```
ReviewId |ClientID | CommunicationSent      
17023|  1950943 | 0     
17202|  1950943 | 0     
17734|  1950943 | 0     
17731|  1948031 | 0     
16822|  1948031 | 0     
15300|  1948031 | 0     
14722|  1945039 | 0     
16125|  1945039 | 0     
17729|  1945039 | 0     
17727|  1943172 | 0     
14552|  1943172 | 0     
17179|  1943172 | 0     
15175|  1943172 | 0
```

So for example I want to set the 'communicationset' to 1 where the clientid = 1948031 and it's not the latest, i.e. highest set communationid to 1 where reviewid =16822 and 15300.

I'm guessing it's going to be some where reviewid is not max(reviewid).

Anyone know how this could be done?

Thanks,

Comment: I recommend against it.  You can always select the latest value and whatever you update today might be wrong tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this update will do it for you:

```
UPDATE T
SET communicationSent = 1
FROM TABLE T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(reviewId) AS 'reviewId',
        clientID
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY clientID
    ) T2
    ON T.clientId = T2.clientId
        AND T.reviewId < T2.reviewId
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
update table1 set CommunicationSent = 1 
where reviewid not in (
  select max(reviewid) from table1 group by clientid
)
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/48858/8)

Comment: Thanks @jpw. I'm sure this work too but already saw the other one earlier have tried it out.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
;with T as(
    select *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ClientID order by ReviewId desc) RNum
    from YourTable
)
update T 
set CommunicationSent=1 
where RNum<>1
```